# Why would a former employer, with whom I am in litigation for wrongful termination, want a copy of my current resume?

Tags: employer-relations

I have sued my former employer for wrongful termination. We are going to mediation and they have asked for my current resume. Why would they want this?

Comment: Why would you even contemplate giving it to them?

Comment: If you sued, that you probably have a lawyer. That would be the person to ask.

Comment: Definitely not for hiring!

Comment: Do you have an attorney / solicitor on your side ?!?!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this would seem to be a serious legal issue, which should be addressed by the legal experts involved.

Comment: They should have it - at least the one they received when they gave you a job.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere they should have a copy of the resume at time of hiring, that is the relevant one, not any new one. I wouldn't give them anything unless specifically asked by the mediator

Comment: If you are in litigation, *ALL* communication should go through your attorney. Even something simple can torpedo your case. You hired your attorney for their knowledge and experience. Avail yourself of them.

Comment: One reason would be to limit their damages. For instance, if you were wrongly terminated, but got a job that paid the same or better two months later. Then, they could argue that you only lost two months' worth of wages. And if you didn't find another job after them, then they could try arguing that you didn't even try to look for another job after you lost the one with them. Basically, a current resume would inform them of which strategy to use to argue their case.

Comment: Any chance you lied or stretched the truth on the resume that you submitted for the job with this employer? Maybe they're trying to trap you.

Answer (score 16):

They're looking for information to use as leverage against you.  Do NOT send it.

EDIT: Obviously, if the mediator orders it, then do so.

Comment: Yeah, don't send them anything.

Comment: Fishing. But, give it to them if ordered by the arbitrator.

Comment: Probably looking for information specifically related to your time with them so they can either call you a liar, or dispute any claims on your resume.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I would agree that my resume at the time of my application with them is what should be important. Nothing to hide but I have had the social opportunities to be in the presence of many lawyers. Always needling for any weaknesses.